# Leer JSON con Php desde URL

Tags: php, java, api

Hola buenas tardes ando aprendiendo php poco a poco pero me tope con que tengo que leer una respuesta json.

los datos que me suelta la direccion web es esta.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "folders": [
      {
        "id": "AQx9QQHj66I",
        "name": "locos"
      },
      {
        "id": "Ul_JH4zI-Yk",
        "name": "Thumbnails"
      }
    ],
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "tutorial.mp4",
        "size": 895113312,
        "link": "https://googledrive.com",
        "created_at": 1604515971,
        "downloads": 0,
        "linkid": "rg458481000",
        "convert": "converted"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

en un archivo php. cree lo siguiente.

```
$url = "https://urlderespuestapijson.com";
$jsonResponse = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
$link =  $response['result']['files']['linkid'];
return $link;
```

pero no me funciona. y necesito mostrar   el contenido de linkid. si alguien sabe y puede ayudarme le estaria agradecido de verdad.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en este caso, lo que hay en `files` es un array (en JSON los arrays se expresan por `[ ]`). Si analizas la estructura en la parte de `files` podrás verlo con más claridad:

```
"files": [
  {
    "name": "tutorial.mp4",
    "size": 895113312,
    "link": "https://googledrive.com",
    "created_at": 1604515971,
    "downloads": 0,
    "linkid": "rg458481000",
    "convert": "converted"
  }
]
```

Entonces, el objeto JSON que buscas se encontraría en el índice `0` del array. Por tanto, el código debería funcionar así:

```
$url = "https://urlderespuestapijson.com";
$jsonResponse = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
$link =  $response['result']['files'][0]['linkid'];
return $link;
```

La diferencia es que después de `files`, ponemos `[0]` para indicarle que busque en el índice `0` del array que es `files`.

Si hubiera varios objetos dentro, tendrías que usar un bucle para obtener el dato de cada uno de los objetos.

### PostData

Cuando trabajas con objetos JSON, no es obligatorio pasar `true` a `json_decode`. Puedes dejarlo como objeto y usar la notación `$objeto->propiedad` para encontrar los datos. Es mucho más limpia que usar la notación `$array['indice']`.

Veamos la diferencia dejándolo como objeto:

```
$url = "https://urlderespuestapijson.com";
$jsonResponse = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);         #No pasamos true
$link = $response->result->files[0]->linkid;    #Lectura más clara
return $link;
```

Comment: Intente de tu forma me ayudo a entender varias cosas muchas gracias.  mas sinembargo seguia sin funcionarme logre solucionarlo agregando un for.

Comment: @Faiver, en la respuesta estaba dicho: *Si hubiera varios objetos dentro, tendrías que usar un bucle para obtener el dato de cada uno de los objetos.* Inicialmente presentabas un solo objeto, por eso lo del índice `0`, si vienen varios es evidente que debe usarse un bucle.

Comment: muchas gracias cedano. te califique tambien bien. :)